# almost finished a program that add and search and delete names from 2d array list but I have an unexpected result in delete section

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, multidimensional-array, while-loop

the code is

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char names[10][31];
    int u=0;
    char new[31];
    char search[31];
    char delete[31];
    int ctr=0;
    int notInList=0;
    int notInSearch=0;
    int y=0;
    int s=0;
    char deleted[31];
    int d=0;
    int q=0;
    //char *p;

    //strcpy(names[0],"mahmoud");

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\t\t§§§Menu items§§§\n");
        printf("1==>enter a new name\n");
        printf("2==>search for a name\n");
        printf("3==>delete a name from the list\n");
        printf("Note !!.. ((if you want to exit the program press(1)and then type ((exit))\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%i",&u);
        notInList=1;
        notInSearch=1;
        if(u==1)
        {
            printf("please enter a name : ");
            fflush(stdin);
            fgets(new,30,stdin);
            _strlwr(new);
            if(strcmp(new,"exit")==0) 
            {
                printf("bye bye\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                notInList=1;
                for(int i=0;i<=ctr;i++)
                {
                    if(strcmp(new,names[i])==0)
                    {
                        printf("the name is already exist \n");
                        notInList=0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (strstr(names[i],new)!=NULL)
                    {
                        printf("did you mean (( %s ))\n",names[i]);
                        printf("1==>yes\n");
                        printf("2==>no\n");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%d",&y);
                        if(y==1)
                        {
                            printf("the name is already exist\n");
                            notInList=0;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if(y==2)
                        {
                            notInList=1;
                            break;
                        }
                        else printf("plz enter a number from the list");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        notInList=1;
                    }

                }

                if(notInList==1)
                {
                    strcpy(names[ctr],new);
                    ctr++;
                    for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++)
                    {
                        printf("%d==>%s",i+1,names[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if(u==2)
            {
                printf("please enter a name you are searching for : ");
                fflush(stdin);
                fgets(search,30,stdin);
                _strlwr(search);
                notInSearch=1;
                for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++)
                {
                    if(strcmp(search,names[i])==0)
                    {
                        printf("the name is exist in the line (%d)\n",i+1);
                        notInSearch=0;
                        /*for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++)
                        {
                            printf("%d==>%s\n",i+1,names[i]);
                        }*/
                        break;  
                    }
                    else if (strstr(names[i],search)!=NULL)
                    {
                        printf("did you mean ((%s))\n",names[i]);
                        printf("1==>yes\n");
                        printf("2==>no\n");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%d",&s);
                        if(s==1)
                        {
                            printf("the name is exist in the line (%d)\n",i+1);
                            notInSearch=0;
                            /*for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++)
                            {
                                printf("%d==>%s\n",i+1,names[i]);
                            }*/
                        break;
                        }
                        else if(s==2)
                        {
                            //printf("the name is not in the list plz choose (1) to enter a new name\n");
                            notInSearch=1;
                        //  break;
                        }
                        else printf("plz enter a number from the list\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //printf("the name is not in the list plz choose (1) to enter a new name\n");
                        notInSearch=1;
                        //break;
                    }

                }
                if(notInSearch==0)
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++)
                    {
                        printf("%d==>%s",i+1,names[i]);
                    }
                }
                else if(notInSearch==1)
                {
                    printf("the name is not in the list plz choose (1) to enter a new name\n");
                }
            }
            //*******
            else if (u==3)
            {
                printf("write the name you want to delete from the list\n");
                /*for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++)
                {
                    printf("%d==>%s\n",i+1,names[i]);
                }*/
                fflush(stdin);
                fgets(delete,30,stdin);
                _strlwr(delete);
                d=0;
                for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++)
                {
                    if(strcmp(delete,names[i])==0)
                    {
                        d =1;
                        strcpy(names[i],deleted);
                        /*ctr--;
                        for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++)
                        {
                            printf("%d==>%s",i+1,names[i]);
                        }*/
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (strstr(names[i],delete)!=NULL)
                    {
                        printf("did you mean ((%s))\n",names[i]);
                        printf("1==>yes\n");
                        printf("2==>no\n");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%d",&q);
                        if(q==1)
                        {
                        d=1;
                        break;
                        }
                        if(q==2)
                        {
                            d=0;    
                            //printf("plz enter a name from the list");
                        }
                        else printf("plz enter a number from the list");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        d=0;    
                    }
                }
                if(d==0)
                {
                    printf("plz enter a name from the list");
                }
                else if(d==1)
                {
                    ctr--;
                    for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++)
                    {
                        printf("%d==>%s",i+1,names[i]);
                    }
                    printf("the deleted name is ==>%S",delete);
                }
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

there is no compiler errors

---

the problem is in delete section and the problem is :: when I enter 3 names and then I want to delete the first name it delete the first and last name

---

I put some stars befor the section that I think it contain the problem

Comment: Some suggestions: Use a debugger. Break your function up into smaller functions for easier debugging and maintenance.

Comment: YUP I forget this until I finished half the program lol